# Access SQL Query to Count Unique Occurrences of One Field Matching Multiple Parameters/Rows, Some Identical

Tags: sql, ms-access

Struggling with ms-access's flavor of SQL queries still, though I've made some progress (thanks to y'all). I have an event log table like this:

## Logs Table

| logID (auto#) | modID (str) | relID (str) | DateTime (date) | TxType (short) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 22.3 | 10/1/22 0800 | 6 |
| 2 | 1234 | 22.3 | 10/1/22 0900 | 7 |
| 3 | 1234 | 22.3 | 10/1/22 1000 | 13 |
| 4 | 1234 | 22.3 | 10/1/22 1100 | 15 |
| 5 | 4321 | 22.3 | 10/1/22 0830 | 1 |
| 6 | 4321 | 22.3 | 10/1/22 0930 | 13 |
| 7 | 4321 | 22.3 | 10/1/22 1030 | 15 |
| 8 | 4321 | 22.3 | 10/1/22 1130 | 13 |
| 9 | 1234 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 0800 | 1 |
| 10 | 1234 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 0900 | 15 |
| 11 | 1234 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 1000 | 13 |
| 12 | 1234 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 1100 | 15 |
| 13 | 4321 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 0830 | 13 |
| 14 | 4321 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 0930 | 7 |
| 15 | 4321 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 1030 | 13 |
| 16 | 4321 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 1130 | 15 |

What I need to do is:

- filter the table by relID, then
- count the number of modID's that have a 15 txType as the last/most recent chronological event in their rows.

So ideally I'd filter e.g. by relID=23.1 and get these results (but not logID # 10 for example) and then count them:

| logID (auto#) | modID (str) | relID (str) | DateTime (date) | TxType (short) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1234 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 1100 | 15 |
| 16 | 4321 | 23.1 | 11/1/22 1130 | 15 |

As part of another function I have been able to count any modID's having a single txType successfully using

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT Logs.modID, Logs.relID
FROM Logs
WHERE ((Logs.relID='23.1') AND ((Logs.TxType=13)))
);
```

Another stackoverflow user (exception - thanks!) showed me how to get the last event type for a given modID, relID combination using

```
SELECT TOP 1 TxType
FROM Logs
WHERE (((Logs.modID=[EnterModID])) AND ((Logs.relID=[EnterRelID])))
ORDER BY DateTime DESC;
```

But I'm having trouble combining these two. I know I can combine COUNT and GROUP BY but Access treats GROUP BY very particularly, and I'm not sure how to use SELECT TOP to get the latest events for each modID rather than just the latest events in the table, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the `logID` from the row with the latest `DateTime` for each combination of `modID`and your target `relID`:

```sql
PARAMETERS which_relID Text(255);
SELECT DISTINCT
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 logID
        FROM Logs
        WHERE modID=l.modID AND relID=l.relID
        ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC
    ) AS latest_modID
FROM Logs AS l
WHERE l.relID=[which_relID]
```

Use it as a subquery which you `INNER JOIN` to your `Logs` table.  Note the subquery evaluates rows regardless of `TxType`.  So have the parent query select only rows whose `TxType` = 15

```sql
PARAMETERS which_relID Text(255);
SELECT l2.*
FROM
    Logs AS l2
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 logID
                FROM Logs
                WHERE modID=l.modID AND relID=l.relID
                ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC
            ) AS latest_modID
        FROM Logs AS l
        WHERE l.relID=[which_relID]
    ) AS sub
    ON l2.logID=sub.latest_modID
WHERE l2.TxType=15;
```

Note I moved the `PARAMETERS` clause into the parent query.  But you can eliminate it altogether if you believe it's causing trouble.

`DateTime` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D).  I enclosed it in square brackets to ensure Access understands we mean the name of an object.

Using your sample data, I get these 2 rows when I supply 23.1 for the query parameter:

| logID | modID | relID | DateTime | TxType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1234 | 23.1 | 11/1/2022 11:00:00 AM | 15 |
| 16 | 4321 | 23.1 | 11/1/2022 11:30:00 AM | 15 |

I get a single row with 22.3 for the parameter:

| logID | modID | relID | DateTime | TxType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1234 | 22.3 | 10/1/2022 11:00:00 AM | 15 |

Comment: relID is actually a string - unsure if this is tripping me up, as I haven't used PARAMETERS before.
But I'm not getting any results from the full statement (with the inner join) whereas the first returns a selection of 3 logIDs out of about 300 rows - not sure the ORDER BY is in the right spot, there. Looking for all logIDs describing a transaction where a modID had a txType 15 as its most recent activity (for that modID specifically, not most recent by the whole table), filtered by relID.

Comment: Please see above, I hit return prematurely and edited. Still having issues. To reiterate, need to:

* Filter all Logs rows by relID then

* Find ALL modIDs where the latest/most recent LogID row has a TxType=15

The first part of it gives me a few random LogID values that don't have a TxType=15 and also aren't the most recent updates to that table with a relID of the one specified (23.1).
The second part gives me blank rows.

Comment: I'm working with the sample data you included in the question.  I added my query results to the answer.  AFAICT, those results are what you want from that 16 row data sample.  If I'm wrong, which of those rows should not be included?  Or which rows should be in the results, but are not?

Comment: Took me a bit to puzzle through the syntax you were using but it seems to work! Had to ditch PARAMETERS and change [DateTime] to Logs.DateTime but that's got it. Thanks so much for the help! Still trying to wrap my head around the particulars.